# Неправильно работает сортировка на c#

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

Привет всем. Решил вспомнить простейшую сортировку с заменой элементов в массиве. То есть, если [i] элемент больше следующего ([i+1]), то меняем их местами. Вот пример метода на c#, но массив не сортируется. В чём ошибка? Делаю замену переменной с помощью третьей - temp. Массив выводится не отсортированным.

```
public void Sort()
{
    int[] Array = new int[5];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
    {
        Array[i] = rand.Next(1, 20);
        Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
        if (Array[i] > Array[i] + i)
        { 
            int temp;
            temp = Array[i + 1];
            Array[i] = Array[i + 1];
            Array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Верно записан блок обмена элементов, всё остальное - нет.. Что, например, делает эта строчка: `if (Array[i] > Array[i] + i)` ? Заполнить массив случайными числами нужно до начала сортировки. Подразумевалась сортировка пузырьком - для неё требуется два вложенных цикла

Comment: @MBo Массив и так заполнен до начала сортировки. Далее идёт условие: если текущий индекс больше следующего, то в теле условия нужно просто поменять их местами.

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog прочитайте процитированную строчку внимательно

Comment: @MBo Всё, сделал второй цикл прохода по j, и всё встало на свои места. Спасибо, забыл об этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Сделано
public void Sort_bubble()
    {
        int temp;
        int[] Array = new int[4];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = rand.Next(1, 10);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < Array.Length; j++)
            {
                if(Array[j] < Array[i])
                {
                    temp = Array[i];
                    Array[i] = Array[j];
                    Array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
        }
    }
```